# Calculating the perimeter of a rectangle using euclidean in C

Tags: c

So a friend of mine is having a bit of an issue getting his code to properly spit out a perimeter (when you input a point in "x y" form) using a structure with functions.

EDIT: The code is supposed to take 4 points, calculate each side using a euclidean function. (you would see the attempt in the print_Perimeter function)

Also, the program is supposed to quit after you hit 'n', but he couldn't figure it out, is there any suggestions that someone could give?

I tried to give him some help but couldn't figure it out myself, either. Sorry if the code kind of looks a bit butchered, we tried a few things and just saved it as it was.

If ANYTHING needs better clarification, i'll try to do my best to reply. Thanks in advance!

```
typedef struct Point
  {
int xCoord;
int yCoord;

}point;

int point_Print(int x, int y)
  {
printf("(X Y): %d %d\n", x, y);
}

double print_TwoPoints(int a, int b, int c, int d)
  {
double answer = (sqrt(pow((a - c),2)) + (pow((b - d),2)));
printf("The distance between point (%d,%d) and point (%d,%d) is %.2lf.\n", a, b, c, d, answer);
}

void print_Perimeter(Point *p1, Point *p3, Point *p4)
  {
int perimeter = 2 * sqrt(pow((p1->xCoord - p4->xCoord),2) + pow((p1->yCoord - p4->yCoord), 2))
        + sqrt(pow((p1->xCoord - p3->xCoord),2) + pow((p1->yCoord - p3->yCoord), 2))
printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is: %d.\n", perimeter);
}

int main()
  {
char quitKey = 'y';
//supposed to make the program quit
while(quitKey != 'n')

  {

point xCoord1;
point yCoord1;
printf("Please enter values for first point, X1 Y1: \n");
scanf("%d %d", &(xCoord1.xCoord), &(yCoord1.yCoord));

point xCoord2;
point yCoord2;
printf("Please enter values for second point, X1 Y1: \n");
scanf("%d %d", &(xCoord2.xCoord), &(yCoord2.yCoord));

point xCoord3;
point yCoord3;
printf("Please enter values for third point, X1 Y1: \n");
scanf("%d %d", &(xCoord3.xCoord), &(yCoord3.yCoord));

point xCoord4;
point yCoord4;
printf("Please enter values for forth point, X1 Y1: \n");
scanf("%d %d", &(xCoord4.xCoord), &(yCoord4.yCoord));

point_Print(xCoord1.xCoord, yCoord1.yCoord);
point_Print(xCoord2.xCoord, yCoord2.yCoord);
point_Print(xCoord3.xCoord, yCoord3.yCoord);
point_Print(xCoord4.xCoord, yCoord4.yCoord);

print_TwoPoints(xCoord1.xCoord, yCoord1.yCoord, xCoord2.xCoord, yCoord2.yCoord);
print_TwoPoints(xCoord3.xCoord, yCoord3.yCoord, xCoord4.xCoord, yCoord4.yCoord);

Point p1;
p1.xCoord = xCoord1;
p1.yCoord = yCoord1;

Point p3;
p3.xCoord = xCoord3;
p3.yCoord = yCoord3;

Point p4;
p4.xCoord = xCoord4;
p4.yCoord = yCoord4;

print_Perimeter(&p1, &p3, &p4);
printf("Enter 'y' to enter new coordinates or enter 'n' to quit the program: \n");
scanf(" %c", &quitKey);

}
}
```

Comment: 1) `void print_Perimeter(Point *p1, Point *p3, Point *p4){` --> `void print_Perimeter(point *p1, point *p3, point *p4){`

Comment: 2) delete `int print_Perimeter(){ printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is: %d.\n"); }`

Comment: 3) at `print_Perimeter` : need `;` before `printf`

Comment: 4) `Point` replace with `point`

Comment: 5) `point xCoord1; point yCoord1;` --> `point coord1;`...`scanf("%d %d", &(xCoord1.xCoord), &(yCoord1.yCoord));` --> `scanf("%d %d", &coord1.xCoord, &coord1.yCoord);
`...`point p1;` --> `point p1 = coord1;` and ditto.

Comment: for 5. I change point xCoord1 to point coord1, then yCoord1 to point p1 in the main function? Just making sure i'm following correctly!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why you didn't wrote an answer?

Comment: @ddz this is offtopic.

Comment: 6) `point_Print(xCoord1.xCoord, yCoord1.yCoord);`  --> `point_Print(coord1.xCoord, coord1.yCoord);` or change API to  `point_Print(coord1);` or `point_Print(&coord1);` ditto.

Comment: 7) `perimeter of the rectangle` need four points. or two point of top-left and bottom-right.

Comment: it needs four points, the standard points given were (1,0) (0,0) (0,1) (1,1), the perimeter is supposed to be 4, but when I tested the code currently, I got 3. I'm assuming there must be an error somewhere in the math part of the print_Perimeter part.

Comment: `print_Perimeter` received only 3 points.

Comment: alright, i was looking at that and asked my friend about it, he said it's supposed to find the length, then the adjacent side, then multiply it by two. I know this was the area where he was getting help with but he had to leave so the print_Perimeter bit may be unfinished or just wrong in general.

Comment: Please consistently indent the code for readability/understandability.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'm literally brand new to the site, a friend recommended I go here for programming help, i'll try to fix that!

Comment: the fix for the indenting didn't work.  See my answer for how to indent the code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. is straight forward
3. only works with rectangles, not parallelograms
4. is tested for the upper right quadrant and point2 is higher and further right than point1. so you will need to test/tweak for the other conditions and other 3 quadrants
5. checks for errors

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
} point;


void print_Perimeter( point *point1, point *point2 )
{
    int horizontal = point2->x - point1->x;
    int vertical   = point2->y - point1->y; // EDIT: corrected from '+' to '-'

    int perimeter  = 2*(horizontal+vertical);
    printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is: %d.\n", perimeter);
}


int main( void )
{
    int quitKey = 'y';

    //supposed to make the program quit
    while( quitKey != 'n')
    {
        point point1;
        printf("Please enter values for first point, X1 Y1: \n");
        if( 2 != scanf("%d %d", &point1.x, &point1.y) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for point1 coordinates failed\n");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        point point2;
        printf("Please enter values for second point, X2 Y2: \n");
        if( 2 != scanf("%d %d", &point2.x, &point2.y) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for point2 coordinates failed\n");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        print_Perimeter( &point1, &point2 );

        // clear stdin
        int ch;
        while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );

        printf("%s\n", "Enter 'y' to enter new coordinates or enter 'n' to quit the program:");
        quitKey = getchar();
        quitKey = tolower( quitKey );
    }

}
```

Comment: This definitely works, unfortunately I forgot to specify that we have to test 4 points instead of just 2.

Comment: 4 points means it is not a rectangle, perhaps a parallelogram or trapizoid or even some random shape